# how to get the table of missing rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

i have two mysql tables

tableA

```
colA1   colA2
1       whatever
2       whatever
3       whatever
4       whatever
5       whatever
6       whatever
```

second table is basically derived from tableA but has some rows deleted

tableB

```
colB1    colB2
1       whatever
2       whatever
4       whatever
6       whatever
```

how can i  write an query to obtain the table of missing rows from the above two tables

i.e

```
colC1   colC2
3      whatever
5      whatever
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM TableA t1 LEFT JOIN
     TableB t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this :

```
select *
from tableA
where not exists (
    select 1
    from tableB
    where tableB.colB1 = tableA.coldA1
)
```

i.e. you select the data from `tableA` for which there is no equivalent data in `tableB`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from  tableA where colA1 not in ( select colA1 from tableB   ) ;
```

Comment: @Bobby Not true. See this link: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/